# Moving to next activity once my QR Code has been scanned

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, serversocket

I have limited Android Experience and had a very basic doubt. My scenario is as follows:

I currently have 2 applications, one being a QR Code Scanner and another which displays a QR Code. These will be running on multiple devices. The communication steps which take place are as follows:

Prior Setup:

1. There is a firebase database containing strings for QR Codes to be generated.
2. Device 2 reads the Code off the Firebase Database and displays it on the Screen (2nd App).

Device Communication:

1. Device 1 has the Scanner App and Device 2 has the QR Code displayed on Screen.
2. Device 1 now scans the QR Code from the Device 2 and verifies through some logic whether QR Code is valid or not.
3. If QR Code is valid, then the following takes place:

Device 1 calculates a new QR Code and places it on the Firebase Database.

The Device 2 should now move from displaying the QR Code to another activity which has the logic to Scan QR Codes of other Devices and verifies if they are correct.

Device 3 onwards must display a new QR Code which is on the Firebase Database which can now be scanned by Devices 1 and 2.

Note: The QR Code Updates on UI must keep happening until there is some sort of indication which makes the Device move to the QR Code Scanning stage.

Things which are working:

1. The 2 activities of the application (QR Code Display and QR Code Scanning) working independently.
2. QR Code Updates on UI whenever Firebase Database updated.

Things which are not working:

1. Moving from QR Code Display to Scanning once the QR Code is deemed valid.

Things I have tried:

1. Creating a Server Socket Implementation on the QR Code Display Application which is running as a Service called by my Main Activity. Client Socket Implementation (placed as a Service) is on the QR Code Scanner, which will send data to the Listening Server Socket once the QR Code is deemed valid. (Issue is that neither data is sent nor received).
2. Creating a Server Socket Implementation on the QR Code Display Application which is running as a Service called by my Main Activity. Client Socket Implementation (placed on UI Thread) is on the QR Code Scanner, which will send data to the Listening Server Socket once the QR Code is deemed valid.(Issue is that neither data is sent nor received)

**I am very confused as to whether my approach is correct. Is there a better way to do it? Code for my service is as follows:**

Device 2 - QR Code Display App:

```
Service
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    private T_Client client;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                client.stopClient();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on close: " + e);
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        client = new T_Client();
        client.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
Display Server Implementation (Called T_Client)
public class T_Client extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = "T_Client";

    private Socket sock = null;
    private boolean running = false;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private Object objIn;

    public void send(String _msg) {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.writeObject(_msg);
                out.flush();
                Log.i("Send Method", "Outgoing : " + _msg.toString());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("Send Method", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        Log.v(TAG,"stopClient method run");
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        try {
            ServerSocket sock1 = new ServerSocket(9999);
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "C: Connected.");
                while (running) {
                    sock = sock1.accept();
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                    objIn = in.readObject();
                    Log.i("Object Read Class", objIn.getClass().toString());
                    Log.i("Object Read", objIn.toString());
                    /* Currently commented because startActivity not recognised
                    if (objIn != null) {
                        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent();
                        dialogIntent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
                        dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(dialogIntent);
                    }
                    Atleast the data should get read here
                    */
                    System.out.println("Object Read Class" + objIn.getClass().toString());
                    System.out.println("Object Read" + objIn.toString());
                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + objIn + "'");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "S: Error", e);
            } finally {
                out.close();
                in.close();
                sock.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Closing socket: " + sock);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "C: Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
getContext().startService(intent);
```

Scanner Application: (Written in Kotlin)

```
Scanner Client Implementation (Called T_Server)
internal class T_Server : Thread() {

    private var sock: Socket? = null
    private var running = false
    private var out: ObjectOutputStream? = null
    private val objIn: Any? = null
    var blockchain_kotlin_copy = SecondActivity().blockchain_kotlin_copy
    fun send(_msg: String) {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out!!.writeObject(_msg)
                out!!.flush()
                Log.i("Send Method", "Outgoing : $_msg")
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                Log.e("Send Method", ex.toString())
            }

        }
    }

    fun stopClient() {
        Log.v(TAG, "stopClient method run")
        running = false
    }

    override fun run() {
        running = true
        try {
            val sock1 = ServerSocket(9999)
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "C: Connected.")
                while (running) {
                    sock = sock1.accept()
                    try {
                    out = ObjectOutputStream(sock!!.getOutputStream())
                    out!!.writeObject(blockchain_kotlin_copy)
                    out!!.flush()
                    out!!.reset()
                    Log.i("Send Method", "Outgoing : $blockchain_kotlin_copy")
                    println("Out is being sent")
                    println("$blockchain_kotlin_copy")
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                        Log.e("Send Method", ex.toString())
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "S: Error", e)
            } finally {
                out!!.close()
                sock!!.close()
                Log.i(TAG, "Closing socket: " + sock!!)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "C: Error", e)
        }

    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = "T_Server"
    }
}
```

```
Service
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    private T_Server client;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                client.stopClient();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on close: " + e);
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        client = new T_Server();
        client.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
Main Activity
val intent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
this.startService(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be interested in [Firebase Device-to-Device notification](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). You might do as follows

1. Device X displays QR code
2. Some Device Y reads the QR code from Device X and `if(verified) sendNotificationToDevice(X)`
3. Device X moves to Scanner activity to read from some other Device Z.

Besides the link above, there are a number of YouTube tutorials and Medium blog posts on how to implement [Device-to-Device notification](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSLgnIC8QFLidgGpAFFlDguEDY5Lw%3A1574707060448&ei=dB_cXcKLG8Tz-gTc_raIDQ&q=firebase%20device%20to%20device%20notification&oq=firebase%20device%20to%20device%20notification&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.0.0..3751...0.2..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.aO4dAmGxEQk&ved=0ahUKEwjCldr3gIbmAhXEuZ4KHVy_DdEQ4dUDCAs&uact=5).

Comment: I would like to send more than just a notification. I would like to send some data between the devices if possible. Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Once a device receives a notification, it can check with the database for any additional data. Use your database as a shared box between producers and consumers. Your actual design will inform how you do this. So maybe Device Y sends data to the database and then shares the primary key of that data/entity with Device X.

Comment: The idea sounds good but then reading and writing Data in the Firebase Database is just ``` myRef.setValue("Hello, World!"); ``` or ``` @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    } ``` right ? Where does the concept of key come into play ?

Comment: by **key** I meant the document name. Recall the name pattern is `collection/document/collection/document` and so on. So you would share the path, or just the relevant portion of the path. For instance if everything is the same except the last part of the name, i.e. `.../{tokenOrId}` then you would share the token or ID for the other device to look up. In your case it might be `QrCodes/{ID}` so you would share the ID since that's the name of the document. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Comment: I have implemented the Notification using Cloud but I am facing the issue that every device in the Device Group is getting the notification irrespective of whether the QR Code is read of the Device or not. How does one circumvent this ?